# What is the (random-functions) tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are 13 questions tagged [random-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-functions).  Most of them seem to really be about random variables and should have the [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) tag instead.

What is this tag supposed to refer to?  Wikipedia just gives the obvious definition that a random function is a function chosen randomly from a set of possible functions, or equivalently a random variable taking values in a function space.  Many possible examples would be covered by [stochastic-processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-processes).  Is there a need for this tag otherwise?

Comment: I had a [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34170/random-process-and-random-function) long ago. I guess random function and stochastic process are the same concept, right?

Comment: The mathematical subject of iterated random functions was (re)discovered by [Diaconis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.65.4923) and others at the end of the nineties, with strong links to (perfect) [simulation methods](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~dbwilson/exact/) of Markov chains *à la* Propp and Wilson. The whole shebang might be a tad too narrow for a specific MSE tag to be needed.

Comment: [This](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/raumann/pdf/On%20Choosing%20a%20Function%20at%20Random.pdf) paper is about random functions but not about stochastic processes. But I agree, it's pretty narrow.